# Allowing users to create bulleted lists, more complex data objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a recruitment applicaiton, I have a model 'Job'

The Admin is able to create new Jobs.

As part of the description for the job, it will have around 4-5 bullet points summarizing it.

It will also have all the roles in the job, and the descriptions for it.

These are only meant to be created for showing purposes, not for filtering, etc.

Here's the question I'm having though, how would you let the user create these bulleted lists, and roles?

I can create data in rails like

```
bullet_list_1:string
bullet_list_2:string
role_1_title:string
role_1_dsc:string
etc...
```

However, if I do it this way, then on particular jobs there may be more bullet points, and on other jobs less bullet points.

How would you handle this situation?

I am thinking a has_many relationship might do it, but if there's an even better solution, would be all up for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My conclusion of features based on your question:

1. It must be flexible to allow any number of bullets, as well as other fields.
2. It must allow easy creation and showing(as you've mentioned), as well as **editing** - showing the same as creation.

Technology candidates:

1. ActiveRecord relationship(has_many)

   This would be filtered out. There is no way to apply that because the fields are uncertain.
2. Text parsing by Markdown

   This would fill basic needs. You can also show creation form for each fields and combine them to markdown when saving. However, for editing, it is easier to edit raw markdown instead of converting it back to the form like creation. Also, it will be less flexible when you want to customizing the view output, say showing part of them.
3. Documentation db like MongoDB

   This would be a perfect fit. All bullets and other information can be saved in a key/value pair.
4. ActiveRecord alternative on documentation

   If you are using PostgreSQL, you can consider `hstore`(for one level key/value) or `json`(for nested level key/value) data field. If not PostgreSQL, you can use a text field and serialize it as Hash or JSON, with less performance.

Conclusion:

If the "Job" model is the core business, I will consider MongoDB. If there are any other limitations, I will consider PostgreSQL hstore or JSON, and finally serialized text field.